# Can you add to GestureRecognizer of the same type to one view?

Tags: uitextview, uigesturerecognizer, long-press

I need to detect long-press on a UITextView, which already recognises long-press thus it has a long press recognizer, can I create a new one and add to it? How will it work then, two recognizers will get the same callback when you long-press?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add two `UILongPressRecognizer`s with different selectors (`initWithTarget:selector:`) to the view.  It should work just like you think it will work.  You may need to return `YES` from your delegate's `-gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:` when both of your `UILongPressRecognizers` are invoked simultaneously.

Note that you will likely encounter problems with Apple's recognizer for popping up the magnifier loupe.